# How to set breakpoint in DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I break my code modules up in DLLs alot.

When I add one of those DLLs to my project, how can I browse it's code to set breakpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created the DLL, add the DLL's Project to your solution. You can do this by right clicking on the Solution at the top of Solution Explorer and clicking **Add...** > **Existing Project**

One solution can contain many projects. You set your executable as the startup project. You can then use Solution Explorer to find the Code in the Modules and do what you like, set breakpoints, make changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DLL is in your solution (assuming you use visual studio) AND is referenced by the process you are trying to debug. Then the execution should come by your breakpoints. IF NOT, you will notice the dot of the breakpoint is an empty circle.